# what's the best way to filter target table using merge statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I need to merge two tables in SQL Server 2008 filtering the source and the target by productid field, let say I've a source table @source (productid,userid) and @target with the same structure, I need to merge the two tables but only for the records having a specified productid.

The sample above it's OK just I need to know if there is a better way to delete only the record with `productId = @productId` not matching the source compared to adding `and TARGET.productid = @productid` operator in
NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE?

```
declare @productid int = 1
declare @source table (productid int, userid int)
declare @target table (productid int, userid int)
insert into @source (productid , userid ) values(1,1)
insert into @source (productid , userid ) values(1,2)
insert into @source (productid , userid ) values(1,3)
insert into @source (productid , userid ) values(2,1)
insert into @source (productid , userid ) values(2,2)
insert into @source (productid , userid ) values(2,3)

insert into @target (productid , userid ) values(1,4)
insert into @target (productid , userid ) values(2,5)
insert into @target (productid , userid ) values(3,1)
insert into @target (productid , userid ) values(4,1);

WITH n (productid , userid )
AS
(
select productid , userid from @source where productid = @productid
)
MERGE @target AS TARGET 
USING n  AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.productid = SOURCE.productid and TARGET.userid = SOURCE.userid) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (productid , userid) 
VALUES (SOURCE.productid, SOURCE.userid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE and TARGET.productid  = @productid  THEN 
DELETE;

select * from @target order by 1,2
```

Comment: I think CTE is not require.
using (select productid , userid from @source where productid = @productid)AS SOURCE .Hence fast.Rest look good man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Avoid using *MERGE Statement*.The reasons why you should avoid read this article by Aaron Bertrand ***[`Use Caution with SQL Server's MERGE Statement`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)***.

You could do this Operation by using Simple Joins or EXISTS. See below..

**INSERT STATEMENT**

```
INSERT INTO Target (productid , userid)
SELECT S.productid , S.userid
FROM Source s LEFT JOIN Target T
ON T.productid = S.productid AND T.userid = S.userid
WHERE S.userid IS NULL OR S.productid IS NULL
AND  productid =  -- Specify your targeted Ids
```

**DELETE STATEMENT**

```
DELETE FROM S
FROM Source S LEFT JOIN Target T
ON T.productid = S.productid AND T.userid = S.userid
WHERE S.userid IS NULL OR S.productid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

The target table does not have to be a base table in SQL Server. It can be a CTE, derived table or even a view.

Old:

```
MERGE @target AS TARGET
```

New:

```
MERGE (SELECT * FROM @target WHERE ArbitraryCondition) AS TARGET
```

Use `ArbitraryCondition` to filter by `productid` any way you like.